# Помогите более эффективно решить задачу по Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Метод принимает 2 ArrayList: a, b. В результате он должен возвратить ссылку на первый лист, который будет содержать чередующиеся элементы 1-го и 2-го списка, т.е. (a0, b0, a1, b1..., an, bn). Второй список изменять нельзя. Вначале я решил эту задачу с использованием дополнительного объекта, создав еще один список.

```
public ArrayList function(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
    ArrayList c = new ArrayList(a.size()+b.size());
       for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++ ) {
           c.add(a.get(i));
           c.add(b.get(i));
       }
    a.clear();
    a.addAll(c);
    return a;
}
```

Но нужно решить задачу без использования дополнительного объекта. Вначале думал просто расширить capacity списка а, а далее начиная с конца поочередно добавлять элементы из списка b и a. Но метод ensureCapacity() не создает заново массив нужной вместительности, а лишь увеличивает емкость списка. В итоге не знаю что делать со строкой вида: a.addAll(a). Приходится просто вначале добавить элементы, а потом их уже заменять.

```
  public ArrayList function(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
      a.ensureCapacity(a.size() + b.size());
      a.addAll(a);
      for ( int i = (b.size()-1), j = (a.size() - 1) ; i > -1; i--, j-- ) {
          a.set(j--, b.get(i));
          a.set(j, a.get(i));
      }
      return a;
  }
```

Comment: Ну расширил емкость, а зачем addall? Не нужен он совсем.

Comment: размер a и b предполагается одинаковый?

Comment: @Sergey, если addAll() убрать, то во время выполнения словим IndexOutOfboundsException

Comment: @Russtam, одинаковый

Comment: Так не надо с хвоста что-то там крутить, и не будет тогда никакого indexoutbounds

Comment: @Sergey, покажите как не с хвоста крутить тогда)

Comment: Так вон внизу сколько примеров и все с начала, не с хвоста.

Comment: Решения все верные, только вот по производительности медлительные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работает для массивов одинаковой и разной длины:

```
public static ArrayList function(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
    a.ensureCapacity(a.size() + b.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        int index = Math.min(i*2+1, a.size());
        a.add(index, b.get(i));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Вариация вашего примера:

```
public static ArrayList function2(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
    a.addAll(b);
    for (int i = b.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int index = i*2 + 1;
        a.set(index, b.get(i));
        a.set(index-1, a.get(i));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Функция делает все верно, но время выполнения слишком долго, к примеру у меня ваше решение выполняется на списке размером 100тыс элементов за 2,3сек (списки я заполнял объектами String с длиной 2 символа), мое решение работает за 0,02 сек.

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение работает немного быстрее и выглядит аккуратнее, единственное я бы вынес объявление переменной index перед циклом)

Comment: @alex_f зачем выносить, если за пределами цикла не используется? На скорость это никак не влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Заюзаем ListIterator

```
public static ArrayList stripingArray(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
    a.ensureCapacity(a.size() + b.size());
    ListIterator it = a.listIterator(1); // расположим курсор сразу за первым элементом
    for (Object i : b) {
        it.add(i);
        if (it.hasNext()) it.next();
    }
    return a;
}
```

Проверим что получилось

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(1);
    add(3);
    add(5);
    add(7);
}};

ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(2);
    add(4);
    add(6);
    add(8);
}};

for (Object i : stripingArray(a, b)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Вроде правильно

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Все правильно, только выполняется опять таки долго и плюс вы еще используете дополнительный объект

Comment: А с чего быстро-то, если при каждой вставке хвост массива перемещается? Используйте LinkedList, тогда будет быстро. Наверное. В LinkedList-e никаких перемещений не происходит. Структура специально для быстрой модификации середины списка.

Comment: Во-первых нам надо эффективно решить, а во-вторых не использовать доп объекты

Comment: LinkedList такой же доп объект, как и ArrayList. Тоже в стандартном наборе классов. И предназначен как раз для эффективного решения таких проблем.

Comment: Но получаем мы все-таки ArrayList, поэтому другую коллекцию уже не получится использовать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
public ArrayList function(ArrayList a, ArrayList b){
    //Индекс будующего элемента a
    int j=0;
    //перебираем b
    for(int i=0; i< b.size();i++){
        //Вычисляем индекс элемента
        j++;
        //добавляем на позицию 1
        a.add(j, b.get(i));
        //Сдвигаем на 1, т.к. индекс изменится
        j++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

**Вообщем по факту расчет такой:** вставляем на 2 позицию 1 элемент из списка `b`. Получаем сдвиг элементов `a` на 1(поэтому индекс позиции увеличиваем ещё раз). И т.д. то есть по факту получаем, что вставлять надо нам на 1,3,5,7,9....